# How I can convert System.Collection.IEnumerable to List<T> in c#?

Tags: c#, sql, ado.net

How I can convert `System.Collection.IEnumerable` to list in c#?
Actually I am executing a store procedure that is giving me ResultSets in `System.Collection.IEnumerable` and I want to convert that result set to c# `List<User>`.

Note I don't want to use any loop. Is there a way of type casting!

Comment: cannot `ToList()` do?

Comment: @CircleHsiao This is not a duplicate. Be aware of author ask for IEnumerable and not IEnumerable<T> here.

Comment: @CircleHsiao This is not an duplicate, because your question mention IEnumerable<T> but the author means IEnumerable.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can use the following:

```
IEnumerable myEnumerable = GetUser();
List<User> myList = myEnumerable.Cast<User>().ToList();
```

As Lasse V. Karlsen suggest in his comment instead of `Cast<User>` you can also use `OfType<User>();`

If your IEnumerable is generic by default which I don't think because of your namespace in question: System.Collection.IEnumerable you could easily use:

```
IEnumerable<User> myEnumerable = GetUser();
List<User> myList = myEnumerable.ToList();
```

Comment: Or he could use OfType

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen Thank you for suggestion I update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to just use Linq's ToList() method.

```
List<string> collection = myEnumCollection.ToList();
```

Comment: This won't work because the OP ask for System.Collection.IEnumerable and not using System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>